# Mocha Using supertest , typeError: cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, supertest

I am learning to use asynchronous testing for my basic Todo application.
But I am finding a bug in developing a test suite for my application,

I wanted to delete a todo using my test suite.

Here is my code:

```
app.delete('/todos/:id', (req,res) => {
    const id = req.params.id ;

    if(!ObjectID.isValid(id))
        return res.status(400).send();

    Todo.findByIdAndRemove(id)
    .then((todo) => {
        res.send(todo);
    }, (error) => {
        res.status(404).send();
    });        
});
```

Here is the code of the test suite:

```
const todos = [{
        _id: new ObjectId(),
        text: 'first Todo'
    },
    {
        _id: new ObjectId(),
        text: 'Second Todo'
    }
];

beforeEach((done) => {
    Todo.remove({}).then(() => {
        return Todo.insertMany(todos);
        done();
    }).then(() => {
        done();
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        done();
    });
});

describe('DELETE /todos/:id', () => {
    it('should delete a todo', (done) => {

        request(app)
            .delete(`/todos/${todos[1]._id.toHexString()}`)
            .expect(200)
            .end(done());
    });
});
```

I am finding a bug like:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
      at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:181:6)
      at Server.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
      at emitCloseNT (net.js:1655:8)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:11)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Thanks

Comment: When you’re running this, is your node server running? Also since your api is promisified, you don’t need to call `done()`. You can return a full filing promise object instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. because of using 
.end(done()) 
instead of 
.end(done)
which is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `done()` before the test-case finishes. That seems to be the issue.

```
request(app)
  .delete(`/todos/${todos[1]._id.toHexString()}`)
  .expect(200)
  .end(done); // pass the callback, not the result of executing the callback
```

Comment: If you are interested in async/await then you would do `await request(app).delete... expect(200)`. Yup, without `done`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it is caused by untidy `done` call. My suggestion is to avoid `done` because mocha supports promises by specifying `return` to promise function.

I'm helping you improve the code as below:

```
const todos = [{
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    text: 'first Todo'
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    text: 'Second Todo'
  }
];

beforeEach(() => {
  // I removed `done` and add `return` 
  return Todo.remove({})
    .then(() => {
      return Todo.insertMany(todos);
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
});

describe('DELETE /todos/:id', () => {
  it('should delete a todo', () => {
    return request(app)
      .delete(`/todos/${todos[1]._id.toHexString()}`)
      .expect(200);
  });
});
```

It is cleaner, isn't it?

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more regarding why we dont use done?

Comment: @abhigyannayak we can still use `done` though but it is more suitable for callback function. And now most of async approach not used callback function but move to promises and Mocha support promises by specifying `return` https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises. If we compare the code and based on my experience, using `return` is much easier to read.

Comment: @abhigyannayak and current trend in test is to use `async await` https://mochajs.org/#using-async--await. It even make code much easier than using promise.